# Categories show 404 error on multisite installation

Tags: categories, multisite, permalinks

I have a wp multisite installation with multiple blogs that are totally separated websites. I use a plugin for domain mapping.

Right now I am configuring everything and I wanted to remove the /blog slug from the main blog, I did it by editing the settings as "network admin". I used /%POSTNAME%/ and / for category and tags base. The posts opens fine opening www.url.com/postname, but www.url.com/categoryname show 404, I tested changing the category base to anything (like /c) and www.url.com/c/categoryname works.

But I don't want to have a category base I want the category post lists to open on www.url.com/categoryname.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have / as category and tags base, at least not without using a plugin like this one:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fv-top-level-cats/

Doing it for both tags *and* categories seems almost impossible to me though.

Comment: I added /tag for tags base but categories still wont work with / as base in any case. If I use another base for categories they work fine. I've also tried that plugin but nothing changes.

Comment: As said, you'll need to run that plugin to be able to do that. It can't be done by just setting them to nothing.

Comment: I tried it but it's still showing 404 errors for categories. It changed the menu links and /categorybase/categoryname redirects to /categoryname, but that still shows 404.

Comment: I regenerated the permalinks and reactivated the plugin and now it seems to work fine, thanks.